# Finding the Lowest sum in a 2d array by picking 1 element from each row

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm, math

I am writing a code where 2d matrix array is given and by choosing 1 element from each row you must output the smallest sums. Sums as in you must give n number of minimum sums

```
#include<iostream>
#include<math.h>
using namespace std; 
int main() { 
    int n;
    cin>>n;
    int hist[n][n];
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<n;j++){
            cin>>hist[i][j];
        }
    }
    int num=pow(n,n);
    int sum[num];
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<n;j++){
            sum[i]=sum[i]+hist[i][j];
        }
    }
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        cout<<sum[i]<<" ";
    }

    return 0; 
}
```

example input would be:

```
3
1 8 5
9 2 5
10 7 6
```

The output will be

```
9 10 12
```

since 1+2+6=9; 1+2+7=10; 1+2+10 
The main problem I am facing would be that I can't find the lowest sum or even the sums I tried to brute force it put it won't work. 
Could you help me fix the code so that at least I could find the sums?

Comment: Even if you fix the immediate initialisation problem, that will not find the three smallest sums - `sums[i]`  is the sum of the `i`:th row.

Comment: You're allocating for n^n sums, but you're only filling in n sums. Try to find out how many sums you actually have with all the combinations. Then try to fill these.

Answer (score 1):

Many problems with your code (it's not even legal C++). But the problem that is causing your current question is that you must initialise `sum` to zero. at the moment you have garbage values in sum.

```
int sum[num] = {0};
```

Some other issues

```
int num=pow(n,n);
```

This calculates `n` to the power of `n`, but there are only `n` squared sums. So this would be better

```
int sum[n*n] = {0};
```

But the big issue, the issue that makes your code illegal C++, is that in C++ array dimensions must be *compile time constants* not variables. So this

```
int hist[n][n];
```

and this

```
int sum[num];
```

are not legal C++. They are legal in C, which is why your compiler is accepting them, but not every C++ compiler would. Since you are trying to write C++ code you should use a `vector`. Here's your code rewritten to use vectors.

```
#include <vector>
using std::vector;

...

vector<vector<int>> hist(n, vector<int>(n));

...

vector<int> sum(num, 0);

...
```

That's it nothing else needs to change.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of brute forcing, why not realize that the smallest path is simply the smallest element of each row and the second smallest path is the smallest element of the first n-1 rows, and the second smallest element of n.

You can elegantly express this by sorting the rows of the matrix first and then keeping a counter of where you are at each row:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

struct path {
  path(int n) : n(n), indexes(n) {}

  // Add one to last row index, then carry over to previous rows.
  path& operator ++() {
    indexes.back()++;
    for (int i = n-1; i >= 0; i--) {
      if (indexes[i] == n) {
        indexes[i] = 0;
        indexes[i-1]++;
      } else {
        break;
      }
    }
    return this;
  }

  int n;
  std::vector<int> indexes;
};
```

Now your problem is as simple as:

```
int main() { 
    int n;
    cin>>n;
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> hist(n, std::vector<int>(n));

    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<n;j++){
            cin>>hist[i][j];
        }
        // sort each row after reading
        std::sort(hist[i].begin(), hist[i].end());
    }

    int num_minimum_sums = n;
    path p(n);
    while (num_minimum_sums-- > 0) {
      int sum = 0;
      for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        sum += hist[i][p.indexes[i]];
      }
      std::cout << sum << std::endl;
      ++p;
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you fully write out the code, please. I am having a really hard time grasping the code you just written down. I am very new to C++